# How to make HTML elements fill up vertical white space

Tags: html, css

I want to have a web page that consists of boxes (div elements) with information that fill up the entire screen. This JSFiddle shows my problem, the red box (number 3) needs to move up and fill up the blank space:

https://jsfiddle.net/whug4kL1/

The following website shows **exactly** what I want to achieve:

http://www.zergnet.com/

When I check the source code of the website above, they use `position: absolute` on the boxes and have `top` and `left` hard coded. When dealing with dynamic data, how can you know the amount of pixels to use for the `top` and `left` beforehand?

So, how do I create a page that fills up the screen with boxes (div elements) leaving no vertical blank space? I'll take any solution I can, but I'd prefer a "best practice" solution rather than some dodgy "JavaScript hack".

Comment: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#fullpagejs

Comment: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: If you check the source of that page, the `position`. `top`, `left` are not from css file. It is added dynamically. You need to use Isotope or Masonry, as @gopalraju suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a plugin like [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) or [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)